# Can I use regression output to feed my clustering algorithm?

Tags: regression, clustering, inference

I'm working on this example:

e-commerce dataset with purchases made by users as well as minimal demographic data like age and gender. The age field is rarely filled. So I want to use regression to fill it up.

My problem is: The only variables available to infer age are previous purchase data.

Can I safely use this predicted age variable (predicted using past purchase data) to cluster users later on with the purpose of recommending/predicting purchase preferences?

I worry that my reasoning is a bit circular.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called imputation.  There are implications and certain methods of imputing your data that are better than others (for example, multiple imputation is often considered one of the better techniques).  But if you use multiple imputation, then it's not just a straight forward running of your purchase prediction algorithm.  Search on CV for "multiple imputation" or just "imputation."  You could also consider using an indicator variable in your analysis which indicates presence of age or no age present and it's interaction term, which could provide some lift.

Comment: Thank you, knowing the term will definitely make my search easier. I still don't know if I should use values acquired through imputation using previous purchase data to feed a clustering algorithm meant to infer future purchase data. My concern is that I'm biasing my clustering model. But it might not be so biased if my imputation is a good fit for my data set.

Comment: If your $only$ concern is prediction, I'm of the opinion, that you can do whatever you want to your data so long as it consistently and accurately predicts your value of interest.  You could try all sorts of things so long as your mean squared error, cross-validated error (or however else you are measuring "goodness" of prediction), is small.  I assume you are validating your model using data that was not used to train your model/algorithm.